# Zend/social engine module database not running

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, module, socialengine

I created a module for social engine, which is zend based, and I added up my.sql file in settings folder, when I install this module, it installs properly but the my.sql file does not run.

I have a entry in the core_modules table. I see a package created in the packages folder, but the my.sql file is being ignored. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong. 
In my manifest.php file, I have set the version to be 4.0.0.

After installation the module does not work, as the menuitems are not inserted, once I install them manually into the database it starts working.

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong. I tried renaming the file to my-install.php, my-install-4.0.0-4.0.1.php and change the version in manifest to 4.0.1 and reinstalled it but did not help. It says 0 query excuted everytime.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me know if you need more info or some code etc.

Comment: Idealy we do need some code showing us that you tried, how things are configurated. Whatever could help us help you.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I found the misconfiguration when I was going through the manifest file, I will post the answer here for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem my self, listing here to help others:

In my manifest file, located at application/modules/HelloworldModule/settings/manifest.php

```
return array (
  'package' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'module',
    'name' => 'helloworld-module',
    'version' => '4.0.0',
    'path' => 'application/modules/HelloWorldModule',
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'description' => 'Say hello to the world!',
    'author' => 'Hardik',
```

The only mistake was in the path, as you can see above, the path has "W" in capital while in real path its in small letter. This was the reason it was not able to find the my.sql file on the specified path, the rest of the module worked fine.

Note: I am on a linux server and the path are case sensitive.

Comment: I have the same problem, but renaming the module name does not help.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be case-related. I'm also on a Linux server.